# How do I save all my created variables to local storage? (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, save, local-storage

Straight to the point.
I am in the process of making a game right now, I have come to the point where I want to save all my variables to the local storage.

And YES I know the good ol' way:

```
localStorage.setItem("var1", 5)

var1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("var1"))
```

That's all good and all, but I have WAYYY to many variables to type all that out manually,
Is there a way to save all my variables to local storage with only a couple lines of code? then on refresh, set all variables back to there corresponding value in local storage

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead of using many variables just use one object? Then you save it once and read it once:

```
let variables = {
    "var1" : 5,
    "var2" : 10
};
 
localStorage.setItem("vars", JSON.stringify(variables));
...
let variables = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("vars"));
```

Comment: Local storage stores strings (DOMString to be exact), so you also need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: @tromgy yes, you're right

Comment: this isnt exactly what i am looking for, the reason behind this is this, when you put these variables inside the object, and when you want to access them, you'll have to do 
    'variables.var1' etc, this is very inconvenient.

Comment: @tromgy otherwise its a good idea. if it werent for that little speed bumb, then i would use it.

Comment: @BenjaminCox, you can also use destructuring `let { var1, var2, var3 } = variables`

Comment: @tromgy yes that may work, but, with a large quantity of variables, typing all of this out would be very excruciatingly painful.